# Looking for a way to represent my Database in XML

Tags: xml, database, export

I am new to the XML. Having a database in postgres, I would like to represent the data in XML format. How may i do that please?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Expressing the database in XML is almost certainly a means to an end and not an end in itself. Without knowing what the point of the XML is, it is very difficult to give advice about how you should go about designing it.

Comment: Check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use some form of application to read the data then parse it to the desired XML format. [Here](http://www.kirupa.com/web/mysql_xml_php.htm) is an example of how to do it in PHP.

EDIT:

You can also use one of these functions `table_to_xml`, `table_to_schema` and `table_to_xmlschema`, etc. See the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-xml.html).

Also have a look at [this](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/XML_Support#XML_Export_Format)

A simple usage would be as follows:

`SELECT table_to_xml('emp', TRUE, TRUE, '')`

results

```
<emp xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <last_name>Blow</last_name>
    <emp_id>1</emp_id>
    <first_name>Joe</first_name>
    <dept_id>1</dept_id>
    <salary>10000</salary>
</emp>
```

Comment: Actually, I was wondering if the major RDBMSs like mysql,postgres ..have such a, so called, application at their disposal or not? Do we really have to write our own application or there is a better way to do that without requiring programming knowledge? tanx

Comment: ok tanx, sounds we are almost there. just I am not very familiar hto how to call a function in psql prompt that would return and XML file. do I have to use it in a select statement? how? select * from table_to_xml("Building",false,false,'') didn't work. could you please help me on that also? tanx

Comment: @rahman Do you mean: SELECT table_to_xml('Building', TRUE, TRUE, '') ? You need to run that query the same way as you do for normal SELECT queries.

Comment: Update: ok tanx, sounds we are almost there. just I am not very familiar hto how to call a function in psql prompt that would return and XML file. "select table_to_xml('"Building"',false,false,'')" worked but how to save the xml?. could you please help me on that also?

Comment: @@Franklin, could you please edit your answer so that I can mark it as the "correct answer"?  the functions are: table_to_xml, table_to_schema and table_to_xmlschema   and a better link for reference would be: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-xml.html